# Doctrine 2 using pdo_dblib to connect remotely to MSSqlServer from Debian

Tags: pdo, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, sql-server-2012

We are working on a project in Apache + ZF2 + Doctrine 2 (Linux Debian) connected remotely to a MSSqlServer 2012 database. For the db communication we are using pdo_dblib along with LeaseWeb/LswDoctrinePdoDblib driver. We create our Entities using annotations and push them via doctrine tool. The problem occurs when we use unique constraints. Either "unique=true" or "uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint...". SqlServer returns the error "1935". The definition of this error is "cannot create index. object was created with the following set options off".

When we have Apache + ZF2 + Doctrine 2 + MSSqlServer in the same system under Windows everything is working fine.

**Update**
It has somenthing to do with ansi_nulls. How can i set them ON using doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it.

In SQL Server'S SQL Server Management Studio:

1) Go to your database. Right Click.

2) Select Properties.

3) Go to "Options" in the left bar menu.

4) Set the following things to "TRUE".

```
ANSI NULL Default
ANSI NULLS Enabled
ANSI PADDING Enabled
ANSI Warnings Enabled
Concatenate Null Yields Null
Quoted Identifiers Enabled
```